# Unnecessary blank page before appendix table

Tags: tables, appendix, emptypage

An unnecessary blank page appears before my appendix, and I am not able to remove it. I wonder if anyone would happen to have any ideas?

```
%------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[headings=standardclasses]{scrartcl}

%\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm, top=20mm, bottom=25mm}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{\arg\!\max}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}

\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
%\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[font=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
%\usepackage[breaklinks=true, colorlinks=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks   = true,    % Colours links instead of ugly boxes
    urlcolor     = blue,    % Colour for external hyperlinks
    linkcolor    = blue,    % Colour of internal links
    citecolor    = blue      % Colour of citations
}

\usepackage[boxed]{algorithm2e}
\SetKwFunction{KwInit}{Initialisation}
\SetKwComment{Comment}{\% }{}
\DontPrintSemicolon 

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% for table footnotes
\usepackage{footnote}
\makesavenoteenv{tabular}

% to fit large table (change geometry of single page)
\usepackage{afterpage}

%Make matrix elements right-aligned
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][c]{\hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{*\c@MaxMatrixCols #1}}
\makeatother

\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \endgroup
}

%\usepackage{lineno}
%\linenumbers

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\newcommand{\mathcolorbox}[2]{\colorbox{#1}{$\displaystyle #2$}}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


% for increasing space between table rows
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.0}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline] \node [anchor=base] (#1) {};}%

\def\drawbox{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[thick, black] ($(left|-begin)+(2pt,-2pt)$) rectangle ($(left|-end)+(14cm,-2pt)$);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{−}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots,dateplot}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,shapes.arrows}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}


\widowpenalty = 10000
\clubpenalty = 10000


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{spacing}{1.2}
\begin{flushleft}
\huge \textbf{Report} \\
\vspace{\baselineskip}
\normalsize
June 2021 \\
\vspace{\baselineskip}
\textsc{Author}
\vspace{\baselineskip}
\end{flushleft}
\end{spacing}

\blfootnote{} 

\newpage
\section{Introduction}

\lipsum[2-3]

%\begin{comment}
\newgeometry{
 a4paper, left=7mm, bottom=10mm}
\afterpage{
\begin{landscape}
\begin{appendices}
\section{Results}


\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\small
\input{table.tex}
\caption{Results}
\end{table}

\end{appendices}
\end{landscape}
}

\restoregeometry
%\end{comment}
\end{document}
```

Here is table.tex:

```
    % Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
% \usepackage{multirow}
\adjustbox{max width=1.68\textwidth}{%
\begin{tabular}
{|l|r|rrrrrrrr|rrrrrrrr|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Par.} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Val}} & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{Model}                                                                                                                                                                                    & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{Model}                                                                                                                                                                                  \\ \cline{3-18} 
                      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Stat} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Stat} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Stat} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Stat} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Stat} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Stat} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Stat} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Stat} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Stat} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Stat} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Stat} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Stat} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Stat} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Stat} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Stat} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Stat} \\ \hline
$par_{6}$             & 6.6                                        & 6.966                   & 9.666                    & 6.96                   & 9.762                      & 6.692                       & 69.665                   & 6.962                     & 9.96                        & 6.966                   & 9.669                    & 6.966                  & 9.769                      & 6.6                         & 66.666                   & 6.966                     & 9.66                        \\
$par_{2}$             & -9.9                                       & -9.692                  & 9.627                    & -9.666                 & -6.265                     & -9.576                      & 69.699                   & 6.976                     & 6                           & -9.96                   & 9.996                    & -9.996                 & -6.26                      & -9.597                      & 6.799                    & 6.966                     & 6                           \\
$par_{6}$             & -6.6                                       & -6.666                  & 9.666                    & -6.626                 & -6.565                     & -6.967                      & 7.522                    & 6.976                     & 9.66                        & -6.267                  & 9.665                    & -6.269                 & -6.692                     & -9.996                      & 69.666                   & 6.697                     & 9.76                        \\
$par_{6}$             & 9.6                                        & 9.796                   & 9.26                     & 9.696                  & 9.556                      & 6.966                       & 26.65                    & 6.976                     & 9.65                        & 9.799                   & 9.265                    & 9.696                  & 9.566                      & 6.996                       & 26.999                   & 6.965                     & 9.56                        \\ \hline
$par_{6}$          & 6.997                                      & 6.595                   & 9.756                    & 6.567                  & 9.967                      & 2.569                       & 76.676                   & 6.579                     & 9.5                         & 2.967                   & 9.965                    & 6.966                  & 6.629                      & 6.622                       & 695.665                  & 6.252                     & 9.56                        \\
$par_{2}$          & -6.666                                     & -9.992                  & 9.626                    & -9.99                  & -2.966                     & -9.967                      & 62.626                   & 6.266                     & 9.66                        & -6.22                   & 9.657                    & -6.677                 & -2.666                     & -9.626                      & 66.762                   & 6.666                     & 9.72                        \\
$par_{6}$          & -9.695                                     & -9.226                  & 9.669                    & -9.226                 & -9.679                     & 9.266                       & 76.692                   & 6.292                     & 9.56                        & -9.626                  & 9.666                    & -9.699                 & -9.762                     & 9.666                       & 696.999                  & 6.626                     & 9.56                        \\
$par_{6}$          & -9.665                                     & -9.699                  & 9.697                    & -9.299                 & -9.799                     & 9.666                       & 66.557                   & 6.269                     & 9.66                        & -9.672                  & 9.626                    & -9.666                 & -9.969                     & 9.626                       & 56.966                   & 6.297                     & 9.65                        \\
$par_{5}$          & -6.666                                     & -9.992                  & 9.626                    & -9.99                  & -2.966                     & -9.967                      & 62.626                   & 6.266                     & 9.66                        & -6.22                   & 9.657                    & -6.677                 & -2.666                     & -9.626                      & 66.762                   & 6.666                     & 9.72                        \\
$par_{6}$          & 6.666                                      & 6.692                   & 6.967                    & 6.596                  & 2.666                      & 5.665                       & 22.662                   & 6.666                     & 9.96                        & 6.966                   & 9.952                    & 6.666                  & 2.259                      & 6.996                       & 29.562                   & 6.26                      & 9.66                        \\
$par_{7}$          & 9.567                                      & 9.296                   & 9.662                    & 9.296                  & -9.566                     & 6.295                       & 662.666                  & 6.662                     & 9.56                        & 9.676                   & 9.767                    & 9.659                  & -9.652                     & 6.662                       & 97.622                   & 6.656                     & 9.65                        \\
$par_{6}$          & 9.595                                      & 9.526                   & 9.696                    & 9.522                  & -9.666                     & 6.267                       & 97.962                   & 6.666                     & 9.79                        & 9.666                   & 9.657                    & 9.666                  & -9.696                     & 6.297                       & 66.697                   & 6.267                     & 9.96                        \\
$par_{9}$          & -9.695                                     & -9.226                  & 9.669                    & -9.226                 & -9.679                     & 9.266                       & 76.692                   & 6.292                     & 9.56                        & -9.626                  & 9.666                    & -9.699                 & -9.762                     & 9.666                       & 696.999                  & 6.626                     & 9.56                        \\
$par_{69}$         & 9.567                                      & 9.296                   & 9.662                    & 9.296                  & -9.566                     & 6.295                       & 662.666                  & 6.662                     & 9.56                        & 9.676                   & 9.767                    & 9.659                  & -9.652                     & 6.662                       & 97.622                   & 6.656                     & 9.65                        \\
$par_{66}$         & 9.679                                      & 6.965                   & 9.562                    & 9.999                  & 9.576                      & 6.666                       & 55.679                   & 6.666                     & 9.5                         & 6.696                   & 9.676                    & 6.66                   & 9.766                      & 2.296                       & 62.757                   & 6.669                     & 9.62                        \\
$par_{62}$         & 9.997                                      & 9.962                   & 9.222                    & 9.996                  & -9.265                     & 9.666                       & 2656.797                 & 6.276                     & 9.65                        & -9.626                  & 9.266                    & -9.667                 & -9.592                     & 9.295                       & 6565.659                 & 6.256                     & 9.66                        \\
$par_{66}$         & -9.665                                     & -9.699                  & 9.697                    & -9.299                 & -9.799                     & 9.666                       & 66.557                   & 6.269                     & 9.66                        & -9.672                  & 9.626                    & -9.666                 & -9.969                     & 9.626                       & 56.966                   & 6.297                     & 9.65                        \\
$par_{66}$         & 9.595                                      & 9.526                   & 9.696                    & 9.522                  & -9.666                     & 6.267                       & 97.962                   & 6.666                     & 9.79                        & 9.666                   & 9.657                    & 9.666                  & -9.696                     & 6.297                       & 66.697                   & 6.267                     & 9.96                        \\
$par_{66}$         & 9.595                                      & 9.526                   & 9.696                    & 9.522                  & -9.666                     & 6.267                       & 97.962                   & 6.666                     & 9.79                        & 9.666                   & 9.657                    & 9.666                  & -9.696                     & 6.297                       & 66.697                   & 6.267                     & 9.96                        \\
$par_{66}$         & 9.595                                      & 9.526                   & 9.696                    & 9.522                  & -9.666                     & 6.267                       & 97.962                   & 6.666                     & 9.79                        & 9.666                   & 9.657                    & 9.666                  & -9.696                     & 6.297                       & 66.697                   & 6.267                     & 9.96                        \\
$par_{66}$         & 9.595                                      & 9.526                   & 9.696                    & 9.522                  & -9.666                     & 6.267                       & 97.962                   & 6.666                     & 9.79                        & 9.666                   & 9.657                    & 9.666                  & -9.696                     & 6.297                       & 66.697                   & 6.267                     & 9.96                        \\
$par_{65}$         & 9.997                                      & 9.962                   & 9.222                    & 9.996                  & -9.265                     & 9.666                       & 2656.797                 & 6.276                     & 9.65                        & -9.626                  & 9.266                    & -9.667                 & -9.592                     & 9.295                       & 6565.659                 & 6.256                     & 9.66                        \\
$par_{66}$         & 9.799                                      & 9.667                   & 9.676                    & 9.669                  & 9.666                      & 6.697                       & 56.626                   & 6.262                     & 9.56                        & 9.966                   & 9.56                     & 9.996                  & 9.566                      & 6.556                       & 66.667                   & 6.667                     & 9.79                        \\ \hline
$par_{2}$         & -6.6                                       & -6.669                  & 9.955                    & -6.669                 & -6.662                     & -6.666                      & 6.996                    & 6.965                     & 9.79                        & -6.966                  & 9.696                    & -6.966                 & -2                         & -6.929                      & 69.666                   & 6.996                     & 9                           \\
$par_{6}$         & 6.6                                        & 6.296                   & 9.966                    & 6.296                  & 6.269                      & 6.666                       & 2.956                    & 6.966                     & 9.66                        & 6.662                   & 9.96                     & 6.666                  & 6.796                      & 6.666                       & 69.692                   & 6.996                     & 9                           \\
$par_{6}$               & 6.6                                        & 6.666                   & 9.962                    & 6.666                  & 6.252                      & 6.576                       & 6.667                    & 6.996                     & 6                           & 6.966                   & 9.966                    & 6.962                  & 9.966                      & 6.296                       & 26.222                   & 6                         & 9                           \\
$par_{2}$               & 6.6                                        & 6.99                    & 9.972                    & 6.99                   & 9.962                      & 6.256                       & 5.566                    & 6.992                     & 6                           & 9.62                    & 9.966                    & 9.62                   & 9.676                      & 9.966                       & 25.656                   & 6                         & 9                           \\
$\par_{2}$            & -6.2                                       & -6.299                  & 9.622                    & -6.296                 & -6.696                     & -6.926                      & 6.667                    & 6.92                      & 9.96                        & -6.666                  & 9.666                    & -6.666                 & -6.669                     & -6.269                      & 29.266                   & 6.925                     & 9.62                        \\
$\par_{6}$            & 9.9                                        & 9.966                   & 9.956                    & 9.966                  & 9.765                      & 6.997                       & 5.952                    & 6.922                     & 6                           & 6.666                   & 0.06                     & 6.616                  & 0.905                      & 1.626                       & 26.626                   & 1.016                     & 0.66                        \\ \hline
\end{tabular}}
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: \newgeometry is going to force a new page anyway, so \afterpage serves no purpose.  Also, you are loading both rotating and pdflscape,.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I see. I had added \afterpage after seeing it on a similar question on stackexchange; thanks for letting me know :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once again, changing [H] to [ht!] seems to fix the problem:

```
%------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[headings=standardclasses]{scrartcl}

%\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm, top=20mm, bottom=25mm}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{\arg\!\max}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}

\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
%\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[font=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
%\usepackage[breaklinks=true, colorlinks=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks   = true,    % Colours links instead of ugly boxes
    urlcolor     = blue,    % Colour for external hyperlinks
    linkcolor    = blue,    % Colour of internal links
    citecolor    = blue      % Colour of citations
}

\usepackage[boxed]{algorithm2e}
\SetKwFunction{KwInit}{Initialisation}
\SetKwComment{Comment}{\% }{}
\DontPrintSemicolon 

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% for table footnotes
\usepackage{footnote}
\makesavenoteenv{tabular}

% to fit large table (change geometry of single page)
\usepackage{afterpage}

%Make matrix elements right-aligned
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][c]{\hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{*\c@MaxMatrixCols #1}}
\makeatother

\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \endgroup
}

%\usepackage{lineno}
%\linenumbers

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\newcommand{\mathcolorbox}[2]{\colorbox{#1}{$\displaystyle #2$}}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


% for increasing space between table rows
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.0}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline] \node [anchor=base] (#1) {};}%

\def\drawbox{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[thick, black] ($(left|-begin)+(2pt,-2pt)$) rectangle ($(left|-end)+(14cm,-2pt)$);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{−}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots,dateplot}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,shapes.arrows}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}


\widowpenalty = 10000
\clubpenalty = 10000


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{spacing}{1.2}
\begin{flushleft}
\huge \textbf{Report} \\
\vspace{\baselineskip}
\normalsize
June 2021 \\
\vspace{\baselineskip}
\textsc{Author}
\vspace{\baselineskip}
\end{flushleft}
\end{spacing}

\blfootnote{} 

\newpage
\section{Introduction}

\lipsum[2-3]

%\begin{comment}
\newgeometry{
 a4paper, left=7mm, bottom=10mm}
\afterpage{
\begin{landscape}
\begin{appendices}
\section{Results}


\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
\small
\input{table.tex}
\caption{Results}
\end{table}

\end{appendices}
\end{landscape}
}

\restoregeometry
%\end{comment}
\end{document}
```

[image]